# Vue jsx, h in render function is defined but never used

Tags: vue.js, jsx

Am using vue jsx and the problem is that eslint is giving me this error about h defined but not used. All the setup and installation and all else is the default vue configuration.

The code works except for the error.

This is my code

```
//HelloWorld.vue
<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  render: function(h) {
    return (<h1>Hello World</h1>);
  }
};
</script>
```

```
//App.vue
<template>
  <HelloWorld />
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
};
</script>
```

How can i solve this issue?
Note: if i simply remove the h it throws: ReferenceError: h is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try explicitly skipping the line that causes the problem

```html
<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  render: function(h) {
    return (<h1>Hello World</h1>);
  }
};
</script>
```

Or you can fix it by removing the `h`

```html
<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  render: function() { // <=== here
    return (<h1>Hello World</h1>);
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: That doesnt works, could it be that my version of vue is outdated or something?

Comment: strange, maybe jsx is causing that, but I'm not sure why. Anyway, added another option for explicitly skipping a line.

Comment: Also, note the discussion here, may be related (eslint-plugin-vue) https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/193#issuecomment-335183854